# IOS swift 3 detect failed screen unlock?

Tags: ios, xcode

i want to detect failed screen unlock in iPhone `ios` is this possible ? , for example device is locked , when i tried to unlock it with wrong password or wrong touchID.

Comment: If your app is for the AppStore (jailbreak & private API out of question), you can't.

Comment: @RajeshkumarR `com.apple.springboard.lockcomplete` is a private API.

Comment: @RajeshkumarR i want to catch the failed attempt not the lock/unlock

Comment: Without use of private api (and an App Store rejection because of that) it isn't possible to get that information. It violates the sandbox/security concept. If you are looking for a solution on jailbreaked devices or an enterprise rollout set the specific question tags jailbreak or ios-enterprise. Maybe someone with knowledge about it will answer than.