Is there any delegate or observer which tells ios app that user has pressed on lock button
I am getting didResignActive when app is in foreground. But my requirement is to pause/Stop PIP(Picture in Picture) running in background when user locks the phone or receive call.
How can I observe this event?

Did you check out this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48293420/how-to-detect-screen-lock-unlock-in-ios-swift-4

If you are using AVPlayerViewController it have allowsPictureInPicturePlayback property

In another case just doesn't use AVPictureInPictureController

@Bram, I have checked. They are using private APIs.
